# Memoryless source of an alphabet

Tags: statistical-mechanics, definition

I am doing an exercise where I have to find an upper bound Shannon's entropy for a memoryless source of an alphabet with $A$ letters. I don't understand what memoryless source of an alphabet means. Does that mean that the probability $p_i$ are all equal to $1/A$? How should I think about this?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a [computer science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) question, not much like a physics question.

Comment: @SolomonSlow this is a part in a problem I am solving in quantum statistical physics so i posted it here but maybea it is also related to CS I did not know that.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is not on how to solve the question, but what the question actually is. Perhaps you can find the definition of memoryless source or alphabet in the same place where the question came from? In its current form the question does not make sense. As you said, even if we ignore the memory thing, it is not explicitly stated in the question that all letters in the alphabet are equiprobable

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "memoryless source" typically refers to the situation where you are drawing a long string of letters from the alphabet $A$, and each choice of letter is independent of all the others and each choice follows the same probability distribution.  It does **not** mean that that distribution has to be uniform; it can be any probability distribution on $A$.